# Xcode autolayout alternating between two different layouts

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, autolayout

I'm experiencing a weird problem in my app where half the time I run it it renders the layout correctly, while the other half, a certain subview is incorrectly positioned vertically.

The odd thing is it happens across different runs, even if I don't change the layout constraints or touch the storyboard at all.

I remember seeing something about a setting to randomize conflicting constraints... I wonder if that's what's happening here. One of the constraints perhaps shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you have an ambiguous layout.

Verify this by using this bit of code in the view controller in question:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
NSLog(@"%@",[self view] performSelector:@selector(_autolayoutTrace)]]);
}
```

Look for views that are ambiguous in the output in the console.

Comment: Yes there is indeed an ambiguous layout. Now is there any way to figure out what the ambiguous constraints are?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the typo. I've corrected that. So now that you know which views are ambiguous, you can now work to resolve this ambiguity. When a view is ambiguous it means that it does not have at least two constraints in both axes (X and Y). You can also print out the constraints on a particular view by calling [view constraints] if you need to inspect them during runtime.

Comment: @eptdeveloper Sorry you feel hurt that I downvoted one of your answers.

Comment: @mattyohe : actully yes i was felt, it's okay if i put answers then i must have to accept downvotes also, no hard feeling for you sorry from me too.